# How to make Frame and Text box appear in GUI?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, textbox

```
from tkinter import *


class TextEdit:

    def __init__  (self, master):
        self.menubar = Menu(master)
        self.topframe = Frame(master)

#===================== Window =====================#
    def window (self, master):
        master.title("TextEdit")
        master.geometry("600x500")   

#===================== Menu =====================#
#......

#===================== Text Box =====================#

    def textBox (self):
        self.topframe.pack()
        self.text = Text(self.topframe, width=50, height=50)
        self.text.pack(side= LEFT)


root = Tk()

te = TextEdit(root)

te.menu(root)
te.window(root)
te.textBox


root.mainloop()
```

How do i make the text box visible in the gui?
The menu is visible but other than that its all blank.
The frame does not seem to appear (I tried coloring it).
No errors or nothing in shell.

Comment: `te.textbox()` - notice the lack of trailing parenthesis in your code.

Comment: Suggestions: get rid of the `#==label===#` dividers; call all initialization methods in `.__init__`